# Group and count by hour in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get group by hour and count but cannot group by hour field.

```
select t_date_time_issued,t_street_name,count(t_reference) from tickets 
WHERE t_date_time_issued BETWEEN '03/06/2015' AND '03/07/2015'  and t_street_name like '%airport%'
GROUP BY t_street_name,t_reference,t_date_time_issued
order by t_date_time_issued
```

Current output

```
2015-06-03 09:34:25.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 1
2015-06-03 09:38:06.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 1
2015-06-03 10:09:06.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 1
2015-06-03 10:14:16.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 1
2015-06-03 10:28:25.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 1
```

Instead I want to get:

```
2015-06-03 09:00:00.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 2
2015-06-03 10:00:00.000 Airport (60/100 14 Day) 3
```

Comment: There are different solutions based on the version of SQL Server you are using. Assuming you are using SQL Server, of course.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time handling...)'

Comment: I tried them but I get 'date' is not a recognized function name. Ia m using sql server 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

Split your `GROUP BY` into a date (using `CAST AS DATE`) and an hour (using `DATEPART`).

```
SELECT CAST(t_date_time_issued AS DATE), DATEPART(hour, t_date_time_issued), t_street_name, count(t_reference) 
FROM tickets 
WHERE t_date_time_issued BETWEEN '03/06/2015' AND '03/07/2015' 
AND t_street_name LIKE'%airport%'
GROUP BY t_street_name, t_reference, CAST(t_date_time_issued AS DATE), DATEPART(hour, t_date_time_issued)
ORDER BY t_date_time_issued
```

Comment: 'date' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: Column 'tickets.t_date_time_issued' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: I know this is simple query but I tried all these steps I got fed up with this....

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that result because you are grouping by date too and they have diferents dates for each row. You should acces just to the hour of the date without minutes and anymore.